# Selenium 4.0.x works in IDE but not in fat JAR file - a CDP implementation for my browser version cannot be found

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-chromedriver

When running a selenium test in the Eclipse IDE, the test works fine, but after building a fat JAR with Maven and running from the command line, Selenium reports a warning that no CDP implementation for the browser version I'm using can be found and thus a "no-op" implementation is being used.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs either due to the classpath being incorrect (hard to get wrong with a JAR that's supposed to contain all dependencies) or due to classes missing from the fat JAR that are discovered as implementations of interfaces at runtime.

There's a standalone Selenium zip file containing a bunch of JAR files that can be downloaded here: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

I downloaded and inspected that zip file to see which JARs it contains and then added the selenium related ones to my Maven dependencies as shown below.  After rebuilding the fat JAR with these dependencies, the program works as expected.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chromium-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v94</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-http</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-json</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are working on local and jenkins execution, please add following dependency. this is enough for your code.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

**those RC related JARs** are only useful when you are setting up **Selenium grid** and **parallel execution** process.

Comment: This question was about Selenium 4, not Selenium 3.  My prior maven configuration for the older Selenium worked just fine as you are stating, but your solution does not seem to work for version 4.  If you are the one who downvoted my question, please reconsider in light of this.

Comment: I didn't down voted your question. But your question is not clear.